# integral of composition of continuous function equals integral of measure set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous and $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function with $\phi(0)=0$. Prove that

$$\int_{[0,1]}\phi \circ fdx=\int m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>t\})\phi'(t)dt$$

First things, $\phi \circ f: f^{-1}([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I can rewrite the LHS as $\int \phi \circ f \cdot \chi_{[0,1]}$ but where I get stuck is the reparameterization in terms of $t$, also can I pull the measure out or by Tchebychevs inequality if $E_t:=\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>t\}$ then $m(E_t)\leq \frac{1}{t} \int_{[0,1]}f dx$ am I just lost or am I getting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>t\})\phi'(t)dt$$ $$=\int \chi_{\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>t\}}dx\phi'(t)dt$$ $$=\int \chi_{\{t :f(x)>t\}}dx\phi'(t)dt$$ $$=\int \chi_{\{t:f(x)>t\}}\phi'(t)dtdx$$ by Fubini's Theorem. The inside integral is $\phi (f(x))$ so we get $\int \phi (f(x))dx$

Comment: what's the justification from second to third step @Kavi Rama Murthy ?

Comment: also, how is the inside integral $\phi(f(x))$?

Comment: $f(x) >t$ iff $t <f(x)$, so you integrate $\phi'(t)$ w.r.t $t$ from $0$ to $f(x)$. @HossienSahebjame

Comment: still confused on how you went from $\chi_{\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>t\}}$ to just $\chi_{\{t: f(x)>t\}}$

Comment: Just see when the two functions have  the value $$1 and when they have the value $0$.  @HossienSahebjame

Comment: and swapping the differentials was application of Fubini's Theorem correct, @Kavi Rama Murthy ?